# How to display blank dashboard in Siny Dashboardbody until user selects options from drop down in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

My dataframe looks like below. I am trying to create `ShinyDashboard` such that user should be able to select options from sidebar panel, and based on user selection Plot and Table should be rendered in MainPanel. Currently, below code is doing exactly what I want. However, there are two issues with below code:

**Issue#1** : Whenever the app is run, the user can see empty table and empty plot as shown below. Instead what is want is whenever the app is run, the main panel should be empty as shown in screenshot#2

**Screenshot#1**
[image]

**Expected Outcome: ScreenShot#2**

[image]

**Issue#2**: Currently reset button can only reset the selection in sidebarpanel. I would like create dashboard such that the mainpanel will show empty screen,when user selects "clear Form" button.

**Dataframe:**

```
structure(list(Systems = c("Sys1", "Sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3", "Sys4", 
"Sys6", "Sys7"), Locations = c("loc1", "loc1", "loc1", "loc2", 
"loc2", "loc3", "loc1"), year = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("2019", "2018", "0"), class = "factor"), 
    frequency = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), freq_cal = c(33.33, 
    66.67, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0), label = c("33.33%", "66.67%", 
    "100.00%", "100.00%", "100.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


resetForm<-function(session){
  updateSelectInput(session,"slct1",selected = '')
}
ui<-dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="System Tracker"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput('slct1',"Select Location",choices = c(" ",d$Locations)),
      actionButton('clear',"Reset Form"),
      h4("Powered by:"),
      tags$img(src='baka.png',height=50,width=50)
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
             box(plotlyOutput('out'))

      )
    )
)


server<-function(input, output,session) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$slct1)

    d %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

  })


  output$out<-renderPlotly({

    req(input$slct1)
    data_filter<-dd %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

    req(nrow(data_filter)>0) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427189/facet-grid-in-shiny-flexdashboard-giving-error-faceting-variables-must-have-at

    ggplotly(ggplot(data_filter, aes(Systems,frequency,fill=year)) +
               geom_col(position = 'stack')+geom_text(aes(label=label), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))+
               facet_grid(.~Locations, space= "free_x", scales = "free_x"))

  })


  observeEvent(input$clear,{
    req(input$slct1)
    resetForm(session)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Provide explanation with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a [conditionalPanel()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html) is the answer here. A conditional panel simply shows its contents based on a condition, which could be based on your input location.

If you edit your outputs to look like this:

```
conditionalPanel(
  #Uses a Javascript formatted condition
  condition="input.slct1 !== ' '",
  box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
             box(plotlyOutput('out'))
)
```

and also edit the `resetForm()` function to

```
updateSelectInput(session,"slct1",selected = ' ')
```

You should receive your desired result.

Comment: @Snel23..It worked. Thanks! How would I address the conditionPanel when I have two Select Input instead of 1 ? Please advise..

Comment: If you have another select input, say its named `slct2`, you could change the condition to be: `condition="input.slct1 !== ' '" && input.slct2 !== ' ' `

Comment: Will it work if my data type is factor ? seems like conditionpanel only works for numeric datatype. I could be wrong. If possible can you please add code to above answer ?

Comment: it will work as long as the condition evaluates to `true` or `false`. Think of it as an `if` statement as a part of the UI. I am not sure how to evaluate factors as an expression, you may need to ask a separate question for that.