# How to reactively change title of ShinyDashboard box in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

My code looks like below where user can select location from `sidebarpanel` and based on user selection data is displayed in `mainpanel`. Next, I would like to dynamically change the `title` of the plot based on user selection. For example, If user selects location1 then the tile of Plot should display "Loc1"(Below image highlights the place where, I need to change my title) .I am not sure how to achieve this in `ShinyDashboard`

Please provide explanation with code.

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


resetForm<-function(session){
  updateSelectInput(session,"slct1",selected = ' ')
}
ui<-dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="System Tracker"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput('slct1',"Select Location",choices = c(" ",d$Locations)),
      actionButton('clear',"Reset Form"),
      h4("Powered by:"),
      tags$img(src='baka.png',height=50,width=50)
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      #fluidRow(
       # box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
        #     box(plotlyOutput('out'))
      conditionalPanel(
        #Uses a Javascript formatted condition
        condition="input.slct1 !== ' '",
        box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
        box(plotlyOutput('out'),status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)
      )

      )
)


server<-function(input, output,session) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$slct1)

    d %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

  })


  output$out<-renderPlotly({

    req(input$slct1)
    data_filter<-dd %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

    req(nrow(data_filter)>0) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427189/facet-grid-in-shiny-flexdashboard-giving-error-faceting-variables-must-have-at

    ggplotly(ggplot(data_filter, aes(Systems,frequency,fill=year)) +
               geom_col(position = 'stack')+geom_text(aes(label=label), position = position_stack(vjust = .5)))#+
               #facet_grid(.~Locations, space= "free_x", scales = "free_x"))

  })


  observeEvent(input$clear,{
    req(input$slct1)
    resetForm(session)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Data:**

```
structure(list(Systems = c("Sys1", "Sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3", "Sys4", 
"Sys6", "Sys7"), Locations = c("loc1", "loc1", "loc1", "loc2", 
"loc2", "loc3", "loc1"), year = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("2019", "2018", "0"), class = "factor"), 
    frequency = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), freq_cal = c(33.33, 
    66.67, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0), label = c("33.33%", "66.67%", 
    "100.00%", "100.00%", "100.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of `uiOutput` and `renderUI`, by moving `box()` function from the UI into the server as follows,

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

d = structure(list(Systems = c("Sys1", "Sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3", "Sys4", 
                           "Sys6", "Sys7"), Locations = c("loc1", "loc1", "loc1", "loc2", 
                                                          "loc2", "loc3", "loc1"), year = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                      3L, 3L), .Label = c("2019", "2018", "0"), class = "factor"), 
               frequency = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), freq_cal = c(33.33, 
                                                                       66.67, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0), label = c("33.33%", "66.67%", 
                                                                                                              "100.00%", "100.00%", "100.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 -7L), class = "data.frame")


ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="System Tracker"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput('slct1',"Select Location",choices = c(" ",d$Locations)),
    actionButton('clear',"Reset Form"),
    h4("Powered by:"),
    tags$img(src='baka.png',height=50,width=50)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    #fluidRow(
    # box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
    #     box(plotlyOutput('out'))
    conditionalPanel(
      #Uses a Javascript formatted condition
      condition="input.slct1 !== ' '",
      box(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
      uiOutput("placeholder")
    )

  )
)


server<-function(input, output,session) {

  output$placeholder = renderUI({
    req(input$slct1)
    box(title = input$slct1,plotlyOutput('out'),status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)
  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$slct1)

    d %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

  })


  output$out<-renderPlotly({
    req(input$slct1)

    data_filter<-d %>%
      filter(Locations==input$slct1)

    req(nrow(data_filter)>0)

    ggplotly(ggplot(data_filter, aes(Systems,frequency,fill=year)) +
               geom_col(position = 'stack')+geom_text(aes(label=label), position = position_stack(vjust = .5)))#+
    #facet_grid(.~Locations, space= "free_x", scales = "free_x"))

  })


  observeEvent(input$clear,{
    req(input$slct1)
    updateSelectInput(session,"slct1",selected = ' ')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What If I want to display text say "Selected Location: " and then Selected location to be displayed ?

Comment: Use `paste(...)`

Comment: Where shud paste(...) go ? before box ? Sorry I am little bit new to ShinyDashBord

Comment: `box(title = paste("Selected Location: ",input$slct1),plotlyOutput('out'),status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This post dates back a bit but I've found a way of doing this without putting the `box` in the server part if somebody is ever interesed ! The trick is to create a `renderUI` only for the box title. It actually works to feed in a `uiOutput` in the `box(title = ...)` argument.

With the correct solution provided by @Sada93 above, you simply need to replace

```
uiOutput("placeholder")
```

by

```
box(title = uiOutput("placeholder"), plotlyOutput('out'), status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)
```

and

```
  output$placeholder = renderUI({
    req(input$slct1)
    box(title = input$slct1,plotlyOutput('out'),status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)
  })
```

by

```
output$placeholder = renderUI({
    req(input$slct1)
    paste("Pasting something before the input$slct1 value :", input$slct1)
  })
```

Hope it helps :) ! Cheers

Comment: Looks cool ! I wait for the OP to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you need to do the rendering of the box on the server side and push that over to the ui

try adding following part in your `server`

```r
...
  output$box_test <- renderUI({
    req(input$slct1)
    box(title = input$slct1, status = "primary",solidHeader = TRUE)
  })

...
```

and following in your `ui`

```r
...
  dashboardBody(
    #fluidRow(
    # box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
    #     box(plotlyOutput('out'))
    conditionalPanel(
      #Uses a Javascript formatted condition
      condition="input.slct1 !== ' '",
      box( DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),
      box(plotlyOutput('out'),status = 'warning',solidHeader = T)
    ),
    uiOutput("box_test")


    )
...
```

Comment: I would like to see something like this  as shown here in first boxes section- https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

Comment: I think @Sada93 provided his answer a few seconds earlier so credit to him

Comment: Great approach by both of you guys!! Thanks for your time and efforts! This is why I like SO so much .Learned something new today :)